# Sender in a Facebook Proxied Email

Tags: facebook, email

When sending to a Facebook-proxied user email address from within a Facebook application, is it possible to specify the name and email of the sender? Or will this always be from a "@facebookmail.com" address that corresponds to the app?

Comment: what does this have to do with programming?

Comment: @Mat - he's using the facebook developer platform and encountering weird side effects from their implementation of a standard protocol

Comment: @Robert Levy: ah, ok. Much clearer how you said it :-)

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you're working with and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I'm sending email via the .NET SmtpClient class in my code.  The code itself works properly.  If I send to anything other than a Facebook-proxied email, the name and email sender comes through as I specified.  It's only when I send to a Facebook-proxy email that the name and sender I specified are replaced with a "@facebookmail.com" address that corresponds with my app.  If the Facebook platform is doing this is there a way around it?  Ideally, I'd like to have a "do_not_reply" address specified as my sender.